# How to configure Liquibase ObjectQuotingStrategy (via Spring Boot) globally for all changelogs?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

How can I configure Liquibase(3.8) (via Spring Boot) to use a certain `ObjectQuotingStrategy` without touching all changelog files?

Answer (score 1):

What about using some sort of parameter? Let's say you will create a parameter `objectQuotingStragegy` and then in spring boot you will pass this parameter to changelog like:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    parameters:
      objectQuotingStrategy: QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS
```

and in your change logs you will use this:

```xml
<changeSet author="veryGoodAuthor" id="1" objectQuotingStrategy="${objectQuotingStrategy}">
```

I didn't tested that, but that's how I would do that if that works.

---

**EDIT:**

Maybe if you need to modify liquibase globally, this could help you. But you have to tweak the autoconfiguration. I didn't tested that.

```
public class CustomSpringLiquibase extends SpringLiquibase {

  @Override
  protected Database createDatabase(Connection c, ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) throws DatabaseException {
    final Database database =  super.createDatabase(c, resourceAccessor);
    database.setObjectQuotingStrategy(ObjectQuotingStrategy.QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS);
    return database;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but touching all changesets would be even worse than touching all changelogs

Comment: I've edited my post, hopefully that helps you

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work due to https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1714